# ckeditor jquery plugin and the blur event

Tags: jquery, ckeditor, blur

I'm currently working with ckeditor and i'm using the jquery plugin for this editor for instantiating everything when the document is ready.  What I need to do is setup a blur event for the instance of ckeditor that is being created.  The below code is what I'm using to instantiate ckeditor.

$("textarea.editor").ckeditor();

What I'm trying to do is something like:

$("textarea.editor").blur();

Is there a way to do this with ckeditor using the jquery plugin for it?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to bind your handler to the editor instance not to the textarea itself. This binds an on-blur-handler to your editor instance:

```
var editor = CKEDITOR.instances['your_textarea_id'];

if (editor) {
    editor.on('blur', function(event) {
        // Do something, Example: disable toolbar:
        $("#cke_top_" + event.editor.name).css("display", "none");
    });
}
```

[(Inspired by skunkwerk@cksource-forum.)](http://cksource.com/forums/viewtopic.php?t=15568)