# How do I attach a blur event handler to multiple CKEditor 4 instances with JQuery?

Tags: jquery, ckeditor

In my page I have multiple instances of CKEditor 4. Everything else in the page is handled via JQuery and JQuery UI, so I'd rather use the same API style for manipulating the editors. Every instance is tagged with the same class, sarat_jquery_ckeditor_nostyles, and I attack CKEditor using its JQuery plugin. So far, so good.

Now I need to intercept changes to the content. I thought I would use [the blur event and the technique explained here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6700586/ckeditor-jquery-plugin-and-the-blur-event):

My code so far... At document ready I do: `$('.sarat_jquery_ckeditor_nostyles').ckeditor(config).ckeditor(callback);`

And of course:

```
function callback (textarea) {
    $(this).blur(function() {
    newcontents = $(this).html();
    alert (newcontents);
});
```

I see my callback being called in the debugger when the editor draws, but the blur function is never called. (In there I would put an ajax call and post the html to a database, server side).

Unfortunately in this case I cannot use the newer inline style for CKEditor (*that* works beautifully for me).

Answer (score 0):

You can use the blur event on each editor like so:

```
$.each(CKEDITOR.instances, function(i) {
    var editor = CKEDITOR.instances[i];
    editor.on('blur', function() {
      if (editor && editor.window && "getFrame" in editor.window) {

        var html = $(editor.window.getFrame().$).contents().html();

      }
    });
  });
```

Comment: The line `var html = $(editor.window.getFrame().$).contents().html();` returns `TypeError: b is null` in the debugger

Comment: This works. It's not elegant, as it uses the CKEditor APIs and not JQuery's, but it'll do `$.each(CKEDITOR.instances, function(i) {
    var editor = CKEDITOR.instances[i];
    editor.on('blur', function() {
      if (editor && editor.window && "getFrame" in editor.window)
         alert('The content for' + editor.name + ' changed and the new value is ' + editor.getData());
    });
  });`